# How to write JIRA-listener plugin?

Tags: jira-plugin

I need to automatically make some changes to a JIRA-ticket's field, whenever certain events happen. It was recommended, that I write a custom event *listener* -- to be invoked by JIRA.

However, I'm somewhat unclear as to *how* to do it properly -- an [online tutorial hosted by Atlassian](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/other/tutorial-writing-jira-event-listeners-with-the-atlassian-event-library#Tutorial-WritingJIRAeventlistenerswiththeatlassian-eventlibrary-Step3.Registerthepluginmoduleintheplugindescriptor) creates a *bean*, whereas the Atlassian's own [`DebugListener.java`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/193299202/DebugListener.java?version=2&modificationDate=1254798446159&api=v2) and [`MailListener.java`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/193299202/MailListener.java?version=3&modificationDate=1270683125527&api=v2) (from the current JIRA source-tree) use classes extending `AbstractIssueEventListener` without any mention of the beans-framework.

I used the tutorial's example, and can not make it work. Should I keep struggling, or should I change over to the other method? Which of them is the currently-recommended and official and which is "legacy"?

The JIRA we currently have in production is version 6.1.7 -- I do not need my plugin to work with anything before that.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone seeing this in JIRA 7.1, I have a solution documented at Atlassian's answer site itself. My solution does not extend AbstractIssueEventListener. I don't claim one approach is better or worse. However, my approach does not require manually loading the listener (as with the extend AbstractIssueEventListener approach). It works automatically.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/51997/answers/37520082?flashId=17814304

Comment: That link is sadly no longer accessible (current browsers don't have a matching SSL cypher and if you bypass that you only get a 503 error). Do you have the solution available somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Code sample of the EventListener, that actually works for me:

```
public class TestEventListener extends AbstractIssueEventListener implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
private final EventPublisher eventPublisher;

public TestEventListener(
        EventPublisher eventPublisher
) {
    this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
}

@EventListener
public void onIssueEvent(IssueEvent issueEvent) throws JiraException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
}

/**
 * Called when the plugin has been enabled.
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    // register ourselves with the EventPublisher
    eventPublisher.register(this);
}

/**
 * Called when the plugin is being disabled or removed.
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
public void destroy() throws Exception {
    // unregister ourselves with the EventPublisher
    eventPublisher.unregister(this);
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, I have rewritten my own code to extend `AbstractIssueEventListener` -- _instead_ of implementing the beans. I guess, Atlassian's tutorial is stale -- because the bean-based class was simply not being used by JIRA.

Comment: I tried this, but could get it working. It always prints `Exception loading class: [Class '...Listener' is loadable from OSGi but no enabled plugins could autowire an instance.].`